# typedef may be undeclared or ambiguous

Tags: c, struct

In a header file I have a single struct:

```
#ifndef _MY_STRUCT_
#define _MY_STRUCT_
struct myStruct{
   char c1[1];
   char c2[10];
   char c3[10];
}

typedef myStruct MYSTRUCT;
#endif
```

And in another header file this struct:

```
#include "my_struct.h"
struct another_struct{
    int val1;
    MYSTRUCT strct;
};
```

When I compile this code I receive the following message:

```
The text "strct" is unexpected. MYSTRUCT may be undeclared or ambiguous.
```

For me both structures are fine. I can't understand why compiler is complaining about this.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Other than the missing `struct` keyword in the `typedef`, you are missing semicolons(`;`) at the end of your `struct`s.

Comment: Please don't use all upper case name for anything that isn't a macro. It will cause you grief in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here's how i think it should be done

```
#ifndef _MY_STRUCT_
#define _MY_STRUCT_
typedef struct {
   char c1[1];
   char c2[10];
   char c3[10];
} MYSTRUCT;

#endif
```

and the other file stays the same.

Comment: I changed to your solution and changed other struct to: typedef struct {
    int val1;
    MYSTRUCT strct;
}another_struct; But the error continues

Comment: try writing a "Hello World!" program. does that run ok? maybe the problem is with the complier

Comment: solved. The path for the struct definition was incorrect

Answer (score 9):

You should have gotten an error for the `typedef` as well, as you're missing the `struct` keyword there. It should be

```
typedef struct myStruct MYSTRUCT;
//      ^^^^^^
// Note the `struct` keyword here
```

And the missing semicolons at the end of the structures doesn't make the compiler any happier.

Comment: I don't get an error on the typedef either for that. I think it's because the missing semicolon sees
`struct MyStruct { .... } typedef myStruct MYSTRUCT;`

which it very probably can't make any sense of, beyond it being a declaration of MYSTRUCT

Comment: My bad, I forgot semicolon. It was always there. I've made the changes suggested by all of you, but error persists.